# What guarantee do I have after is_regular_file?

Tags: c++, boost-filesystem

Considering a `boost::filesystem::path p`, is it possible to have  `boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(p) == true` and `std::ifstream(p.c_str()).is_open() == false` in the same time? If yes, in which kind of situation?

The context is the writing of an assert for a comparison function:

```
bool identical_files(const boost::filesystem::path& p1, const boost::filesystem::path& p2)
{
  assert(boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(p1));
  assert(boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(p2));
  std::ifstream f1(p1.c_str());
  assert(f1.is_open()); // IS THIS REDUNDANT ???
  std::ifstream f2(p2.c_str());
  assert(f2.is_open());
  // ...
  // ...
  // ...
}
```

Comment: I find that for most file system operations the *better ask forgiveness than permission* paradigm works best (as opposed to the *look before you leap* paradigm). In your case that means that `is_regular_file(p1)` is a redundant check, because you will always need `f1.is_open()` anyway.

Comment: But `f1.is_open()` is `true` when `p1` is a directory.

Comment: Then first do `f1.is_open()`, and then do `is_regular_file()`, you can take advantage of short-circuiting: `if(f1.is_open() and f1.is_regular_file())`

Comment: @Escualo that does not guarantee that the stream you opened is the same object that `is_regular_file()` is checking. On linux, in particular, you can delete a path to an object (inode) which is still in use, and create a new inode at the old path. New filesystem operations then operate on the new inode, not the old, while operations on the old inode (eg, reading from that stream) continue as normal...

Comment: 1.) You check with `assert` therefore it does not matter for release builds therefore it does not matter that much. 2.) Just compare the paths for identical files because (e.g. linux) a lot of things are files.

Comment: @knivil : 1) You're right, but it's a simplified example. I removed the more complex error management here. Actually I use exception or assert depending of some external configuration. 2) What do you mean by "compare the paths" ?

Comment: Moreover, I'm really surprised by the downvote on this question. Could you explain it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only guarantee you have is that *at the time of the call, the path was a regular file*. Because the filesystem *is implicitly a race condition*, the call between `boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(p1)` and `std::ifstream f1(p1.c_str())` may actually be referring to two different *objects*.

Consider the scenario:

- Process 1 calls `boost::filesystem::is_regular_file(p1)`, succeeds and determines it's a "normal" file
- Process 2 deletes path pointed to by `p1`
- Process 1 calls `std::ifstream f1(p1.c_str())`, and fails to open the file

Can you see the race condition here?

Comment: It also may fail if the process doesn't have permission to access the target file; the file will exist, but opening it will fail. The `is_regular_file` check also excludes fifos and character devices.

Comment: Thanks for this specific example. In my case, I prefer ignore concurence problems, because it's probably never used in a multi-threaded context. My question is more about the same file, without thrid-party trying to trap my code. ;-) But the answer of Colonel Thirty Two is relevant in my case.